# error in getting ajax response in java script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

In my project am using ajax for sending message the problem is i can't get the response in the ajax function the function works perfectly before,Can't find exact cause of the issue help me to solve it

**ajax**

```
var str = {
  message:message, department_id:department, email:email, username:name
};

$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/savemessage',
  dataType:"json",
  data: str,
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#sentchat') . hide();
    $('#chatmessage') . show();

    $('#userchat') . html(msg . dataid);
    $('.chat-box-content') . hide();

    $('#adminname span').html('waiting for admins reply');

    var elem = document . getElementById('userchat');
    elem.scrollTop = elem . scrollHeight;
  }
});
```

**php controller**

```
function savemessage() {

  extract($this->input->post());



  $data['message_id'] = $this->session->userdata('msgid');
  $data['username'] = $username;
  $data['email'] = $email;
  $data['department_id'] = $department_id;
  $data['message'] = $message;
  $data['datetime'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


  $data['status'] = 'new';
  $data['message_by'] = '1';
  $this->db->insert('message', $data);

  echo json_encode($username);
  exit;
}
```

I cant get the response in it help me to solve it

Comment: undefined `useremail & dptid`

Comment: Can you also see the correct url you may need to use `" "` like `"<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/savemessage"`

Comment: `extract($this->input->post());`  YUK, at least it is inside a function scope and not the global scope

Comment: there is no error in the savemessage function but i can't get response from the function in the ajax

Comment: Use encode type.
Just use:

`header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $username;

instead of `echo json_encode($username);`

Answer (score 0):

You use ajax to communicate with a PHP script, inside the PHP script you could have the content of the function you want to execute. For example in your code:

```
$.ajax( {
  type: "POST",
  url:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/savemessage.php',
  dataType:"json",
  data: {myData:str},
  success: function(msg) {
    $('#sentchat') . hide();
    $('#chatmessage') . show();

    $('#userchat') . html(msg . dataid);
    $('.chat-box-content') . hide();

    $('#adminname span').html('waiting for admins reply');

    var elem = document . getElementById('userchat');
    elem.scrollTop = elem . scrollHeight;
  }
});
```

Then, on the server side the php script "savemessage.php" would receive the POST action, so you could have:

```
if(isset($_POST['myData']) && !empty($_POST['myData'])) {
  $obj = $_POST['myData'];
  //rest of your code

  echo json_encode($username);
  exit;
}
```

However from your code I cannot see $username defined, so that probably would return an error.

Comment: the value $user name will be get from the extract of post what i need is i can't get response from the controller savemessage.php

Comment: The php script is in a third party URL? because that won't work. Try to echo something in the script and in the 'success: function' print the variable "msg", see if you have a response.

Comment: URL is working fine i have tried json_encode('hai')  instead of json_encode($username) that too can't get in response function

Comment: Did you tried the code I posted? How do you know the url is working fine? How are you printing the response? you have to update your question or give more information. I tried this same code and is working for me.